# iOS Build Failure in Codemagic due to Missing Code Signing Certificates for TestFlight Deployment without MAC

Tags: flutter, code-signing, testflight, provisioning-profile, codemagic

I have a Flutter app that I want to test on iOS devices via TestFlight without having to register the devices' UDIDs, but I don't have a Mac or an iPhone. I'm using Codemagic, but I'm encountering issues during the iOS build process. Here's the output:

```
Archiving com.giuse.testDeploy...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
No valid code signing certificates were found
You can connect to your Apple Developer account by signing in with your Apple ID
in Xcode and create an iOS Development Certificate as well as a Provisioning 
Profile for your project by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected under Signing & Capabilities > Team. 
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again
  5- Trust your newly created Development Certificate on your iOS device
     via Settings > General > Device Management > [your new certificate] > Trust

For more information, please visit:
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/
  AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
No development certificates available to code sign app for device deployment

Build failed :|
Failed to build for iOS
```

I set the code signing to Automatic. I've entered the App Store Connect API key and the Bundle Identifier. I set the Provisioning Profile Type to App Store. For App Store Connect, I enabled App Store Connect publishing and submit to TestFlight beta review.